# Sqlite3 update statement problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

how to create SQl statement for update using 'where' condition with 'name', how to bind this name to sql statement...

```
///example 
const char *sql = "update profile set name = ? ,Lname = ?, date = ?,phno = ? ,image = ? , id= ? where **name=?**;";
```

Comment: can you build the string with these bind variables explicitly mentioned?

i.e to construct the string by concatenating the string with both constant strings and the variables?

Comment: I want to update these values based on NAME value so my where condition has to bind the name value. How to do that.  I can update the values using static ID.

Comment: Added sqlite3 tag because it is an sqlite3 question

Comment: Don't go this route.  Use a wrapper instead (FMDB is the best):  http://code.google.com/p/flycode

Answer (score 4):

What is the problem?  You can just use [sqlite3_bind()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)  Each parameter has a numbered index starting at 1.  You just call sqlite3_bind() for each of the question marks.  The first 'name' is parameter number 1 and the second one is parameter number 7.